# Login with angularjs and php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Im going to try to build an login system with angularjs and php. However, I don't know how Im going to handle the sessions and the redirection when the user has successfully logged in?

Should I start a session in the backend with PHP, and then return it to back to angular? Should I use window.location.href when Im going to redirect the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Php session and return it to Angular service. Then you can share your user information with service to other controllers.

I recommend you to use ngRoute and shared service which contains user information. This method is very fast and secure.

I just edit my answer and made a quick example for you.

```
var doc = angular.module('doc',
[
    'ngRoute'
]);

doc.service('link', function () {//Creating my service
    this.user = false;//Here is my user object. I am changing these datas in the login section.

});

doc.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
     .when('/homepage', {
         templateUrl: 'view/homepage.html',
         controller: 'homePage',
     })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'view/login.html',
        controller: 'login',
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

doc.controller("login", function ($scope, $timeout, link, $location) { //As you see I sent 'link' as a parameter. So I can easily use my service and the user data.
    $scope.username = "";
    $scope.password = "";
    $scope.login = function () {
        $.get("/login.php", {username:$scope.username,password:$scope.password},function(data){
            if(data){
                link.user = JSON.parse(data); // I am parsing my json data and save to link.user
                $location.path("/homapage");
            }
        });
    }
});


doc.controller("homePage", function ($scope, $timeout, link, $location) { //As you see I sent 'link' as a parameter. So I can easily use my service and the user data.
    if(link.user){
        console.log(link.user); // I can access my user!
    }else{
        $location.path("/login");
    }
});
```

As you see my service contains my user datas which I initialized at the login page. Now I am using them in my controllers easily.